# Prove that in $S_7$ if $(a, b)$ is modular pair then $(b, a)$ is modular pair.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

According to the definition we saw in theory, in any lattice, a modular pair is a pair $(a, b)$ of elements such that for all $x$ satisfying $$ a \land b \leq x \leq b, $$ we have $$ (x \lor a) \land b = x $$

Can you help me prove that in $S_7$, if $(a, b)$ is modular pair, then $(b, a)$ is modular pair?

Thanks

[image: S7 lattice]

Comment: **Hint:** Name the elements of $S_7$ and simply write up all the modular pairs.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for the suggestion! I wrote all the pairs, and found that every pair of elements of the lattice (except for the 2 corners of the left and right in the diagram), are modular pair. There is not a more efficient way, right? Thanks

Comment: jacob-- To help those who might answer, it would be good if you edit your diagram and provide labels like A,B,etc to the nodes. That way responders will have a way to refer to the nodes.